# flex-basis not working, image disappears in Safari

Tags: html, css, safari, flexbox

I know my question is quite similar to other people, but the case is different.

This is how it shown in **Chrome**
[image]

**Safari**
[image]

You can see the map disappears in safari. I have tried some methods including min-height in percentage but not working.

Take note: I want to make the image and text columns have same height, the size will be changed according to screen size, so **please don't suggest a fix width and height for me**.

Hoping that some of you could provide me with some advice. Thanks!

```js
$('#tabs').tabs({
    activate: function (event, ui) {}
});
```

```css
* {margin:0;padding:0;box-sizing:border-box}
html, body {width:100%}

#Contact, #contact-panel{ height: 92%;}

.fullwidth_contact{
  display: flex;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -webkit-flexbox;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  -webkit-flex-direction: row;
  -moz-flex-direction: row;
  -ms-flex-direction: row;
  height: 92%;
  margin: 0;
  padding:0;
}

.rowdisplay_contact {
  display: flex;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -webkit-flexbox;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  -webkit-flex-direction: column;
  -moz-flex-direction: column;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  height: 90%;
  margin: 0;
  padding:0;
}


.repeat-xcontact {
  flex: 1;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
}

.width70{flex-basis: 70%;}
.width30{flex-basis: 30%;}

.country_box{ 
 font-size: 25px;
 line-height: 1.2em;
 padding: 12% 10%;
 background-color: #5ba4ee;
}

.address_box{
 padding: 12% 10%;
 background-color: #ccc;
}

.map { background-image: url("http://geology.com/world/world-map.gif");}

ul.tabs{
 margin:0;
 padding: 16% 0 0 0;
    list-style-type: none;
}

ul.tabs li{
 padding: 5px 0;
}

ul.tabs li a{
 color: #fff;
 font-weight: bold;
}

ul.tabs li a:hover, .ui-state-active{
 font-weight: bold;
 color: #1d70c4;
 outline:none;
}

.ui-state-active a,
.ui-state-active a:link,
.ui-state-active a:visited {
 font-weight: bold;
 color: #1d70c4;
 text-decoration: none;
}

ul.tabs li a:focus {
    outline:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div id="tabs" class="fullwidth_contact">
  <div class="repeat-xcontact map width70"></div>
  
  <div class="repeat-xcontact width30">
 <!-- <div class="rowdisplay_contact width100"> -->
   <div class="repeat-xcontact country_box">
  <div class="txt8">CONTACT</div><br/>
  <ul class="tabs" data-persist="true">
   <li><a href="#view1">Content 1</a></li>
   <li><a href="#view2">Content 2</a></li>
   <li><a href="#view3">Content 3</a></li>
  </ul>
   </div>
   <div class="repeat-xcontact address_box">
  <div id="view1">
   <p class="country_title">Content 1</p>
   <p>Cras dignissim lectus sed dui ullamcorper, et suscipit justo vehicula.</p>
   <p>T &nbsp;&nbsp; 1234 5678</p>
   <p>F &nbsp;&nbsp; 1234 5678</p>
   <p>E &nbsp;&nbsp; <script language="JavaScript"><!--
   var name = "info";
   var domain = "test.com";
   document.write('<a href=\"mailto:' + name + '@' + domain + '\">');
   document.write(name + '@' + domain + '</a>');
   // --><!--</script></p>
  </div>
  <div id="view2">
   <p class="country_title">Content 2</p>
   <p>Cras dignissim lectus sed dui ullamcorper, et suscipit justo vehicula.</p>
   <p>T &nbsp;&nbsp; 1234 5678</p>
   <p>F &nbsp;&nbsp; 1234 5678</p>
   <p>E &nbsp;&nbsp; <script language="JavaScript"><!--
   var name = "info";
   var domain = "test.com";
   document.write('<a href=\"mailto:' + name + '@' + domain + '\">');
   document.write(name + '@' + domain + '</a>');
   // --><!--</script></p>
  </div>
  <div id="view3">
   <p class="country_title">Content 3</p>
   <p>Cras dignissim lectus sed dui ullamcorper, et suscipit justo vehicula.</p>
   <p>T &nbsp;&nbsp; 1234 5678</p>
   <p>F &nbsp;&nbsp; 1234 5678</p>
   <p>E &nbsp;&nbsp; <script language="JavaScript"><!--
   var name = "info";
   var domain = "test.com";
   document.write('<a href=\"mailto:' + name + '@' + domain + '\">');
   document.write(name + '@' + domain + '</a>');
   // --><!--</script></p>
  </div>
   </div>
 <!-- </div> -->
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I just tested your snippet on Safari (v11.0.2), Chrome (v63.0.3239.132) and FireFox (v57.0.4) and it seems to work on all of them.

[image: Snippet test in Safari]

I also made a codepen to test your problem: 
https://codepen.io/mike-scheurwater/pen/zpWxOO

Can you tell me if it works and if not, what version(s) are you using?

```js
$('#tabs').tabs({
    activate: function (event, ui) {}
});
```

```css
* {margin:0;padding:0;box-sizing:border-box}
html, body {width:100%}

#Contact, #contact-panel{ height: 92%;}

.fullwidth_contact{
  display: flex;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -webkit-flexbox;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  -webkit-flex-direction: row;
  -moz-flex-direction: row;
  -ms-flex-direction: row;
  height: 92%;
  margin: 0;
  padding:0;
}

.rowdisplay_contact {
  display: flex;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -webkit-flexbox;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  -webkit-flex-direction: column;
  -moz-flex-direction: column;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  height: 90%;
  margin: 0;
  padding:0;
}


.repeat-xcontact {
  flex: 1;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
}

.width70{flex-basis: 70%;}
.width30{flex-basis: 30%;}

.country_box{ 
 font-size: 25px;
 line-height: 1.2em;
 padding: 12% 10%;
 background-color: #5ba4ee;
}

.address_box{
 padding: 12% 10%;
 background-color: #ccc;
}

.map { background-image: url("http://geology.com/world/world-map.gif");}

ul.tabs{
 margin:0;
 padding: 16% 0 0 0;
    list-style-type: none;
}

ul.tabs li{
 padding: 5px 0;
}

ul.tabs li a{
 color: #fff;
 font-weight: bold;
}

ul.tabs li a:hover, .ui-state-active{
 font-weight: bold;
 color: #1d70c4;
 outline:none;
}

.ui-state-active a,
.ui-state-active a:link,
.ui-state-active a:visited {
 font-weight: bold;
 color: #1d70c4;
 text-decoration: none;
}

ul.tabs li a:focus {
    outline:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div id="tabs" class="fullwidth_contact">
  <div class="repeat-xcontact map width70"></div>
  
  <div class="repeat-xcontact width30">
 <!-- <div class="rowdisplay_contact width100"> -->
   <div class="repeat-xcontact country_box">
  <div class="txt8">CONTACT</div><br/>
  <ul class="tabs" data-persist="true">
   <li><a href="#view1">Content 1</a></li>
   <li><a href="#view2">Content 2</a></li>
   <li><a href="#view3">Content 3</a></li>
  </ul>
   </div>
   <div class="repeat-xcontact address_box">
  <div id="view1">
   <p class="country_title">Content 1</p>
   <p>Cras dignissim lectus sed dui ullamcorper, et suscipit justo vehicula.</p>
   <p>T &nbsp;&nbsp; 1234 5678</p>
   <p>F &nbsp;&nbsp; 1234 5678</p>
   <p>E &nbsp;&nbsp; <script language="JavaScript"><!--
   var name = "info";
   var domain = "test.com";
   document.write('<a href=\"mailto:' + name + '@' + domain + '\">');
   document.write(name + '@' + domain + '</a>');
   // --><!--</script></p>
  </div>
  <div id="view2">
   <p class="country_title">Content 2</p>
   <p>Cras dignissim lectus sed dui ullamcorper, et suscipit justo vehicula.</p>
   <p>T &nbsp;&nbsp; 1234 5678</p>
   <p>F &nbsp;&nbsp; 1234 5678</p>
   <p>E &nbsp;&nbsp; <script language="JavaScript"><!--
   var name = "info";
   var domain = "test.com";
   document.write('<a href=\"mailto:' + name + '@' + domain + '\">');
   document.write(name + '@' + domain + '</a>');
   // --><!--</script></p>
  </div>
  <div id="view3">
   <p class="country_title">Content 3</p>
   <p>Cras dignissim lectus sed dui ullamcorper, et suscipit justo vehicula.</p>
   <p>T &nbsp;&nbsp; 1234 5678</p>
   <p>F &nbsp;&nbsp; 1234 5678</p>
   <p>E &nbsp;&nbsp; <script language="JavaScript"><!--
   var name = "info";
   var domain = "test.com";
   document.write('<a href=\"mailto:' + name + '@' + domain + '\">');
   document.write(name + '@' + domain + '</a>');
   // --><!--</script></p>
  </div>
   </div>
 <!-- </div> -->
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I copied your snippet because i need to add code when adding a codepen-link.

Comment: I'm using Mac safari 5.1.10 and windows safari 5.1.7. Both got the same issue. Do you have any solution? I have been struggling with it for a few days :(

Comment: I'm using the same settings as you do, but it works here.

Comment: oh man, I think my windows and mac are too old till I can only get old version of safari. Will try on windows 10 later. Thanks for reminding me!

Comment: If you check this site (https://caniuse.com/#search=flex) you can see that Safari 5.1 does not support Display:flex;
So that is the problem :)

Comment: yesterday I tried in windows 10, the result is still same :(, I think I need to find some solutions to solve it. Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: If display: flex; doesn't work, you can use `display: table;` on #tabs and `display:table-cell; width: 70%;` on .repeat-xcontact.
You can always check [modernizer](https://modernizr.com/docs/#flexbox) for the fallbacks.

Comment: If this is the answer you were looking for, could you put the question as solved and set my answer as the right one?